# How to print the exact time in UILabel and keep it up to date?

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the top of my application i have the date and time in a large font. The system time is still displayed in the top iOS header bar-thingy.

I want to show the exact time in this label but with my current approach there's a delay. It would make sense in the current approach to have a delay of less then a second but sometimes it's even 5 seconds. In the simulator there is almost no delay.

Current approach:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Start timer for every minute to update date and time
    long seconds = [_dateCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    _timerEveryMinute = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:((long)60 - seconds) target:self selector:@selector(setInitialTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)setInitialTimer {
    _timerEveryMinute = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(doEveryMinute) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self doEveryMinute];
}

-(void)doEveryMinute {
    [self setTopDate:[NSDate date]];
}

-(void)setTopDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSMutableArray *dateStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM"];
    [dateStrings addObject:[_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    [dateStrings addObject:[_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    [dateStrings addObject:[_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];

    NSMutableAttributedString *dateStringStyled = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[dateStrings componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
    [dateStringStyled addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont roomLightWithSize:36]
                             range:NSMakeRange( ((NSString *)dateStrings[0]).length + 1, ((NSString *)dateStrings[1]).length)];

    _lblDate.attributedText = dateStringStyled;

    [_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    _lblWeekday.text = [_dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

In short.. My first initial timer is set to run at the remaining seconds until the next minute. After that I set my timer to run every minute.

I would like some way that I can start a method at exactly the next minute. Something like 'observe clock until ..'

Any ideas?

**[22:33] Added the setTopDate.**
Doesn't do all that much though...

**[day + 1] Complete solution**

If it may help others, the complete code below to get something executed on exactly 1 minute. The same approach of course works for seconds or hours.

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateComponents *minuteComponent;
@end

@implementation
-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _minuteComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        _minuteComponent.minute = 1;
        [self doEveryMinute];
    }
}

-(void)doEveryMinute {
    NSLog(@"Minute passed: %@", [NSDate date]);

    // Shedule itself again to run at the next minute
    NSDateComponents *flatComponent = [_dateCalendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute)
                                                       fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *flatMinute = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:flatComponent];
    flatMinute = [_dateCalendar dateByAddingComponents:_minuteComponent toDate:flatMinute options:0];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:[[NSTimer alloc]initWithFireDate:flatMinute
                                                                interval:0
                                                                  target:self
                                                                selector:@selector(doEveryMinute)
                                                                userInfo:nil
                                                                 repeats:NO]
                                forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    //Execute some code every minute
}

@end
```

Comment: do some math to find out how many seconds to next minute

Comment: Is setTopDate a method? Could you post that code?

Comment: @BryanChen: ((long)60 - seconds) seems correct to me.. ?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq sorry I didn't fully read your code and missed that part.... You may have too much workload on main thread that delay the method calling. On simulator, because your machine is more powerful, so it wasn't an issue. You can use profiling tool to figure out the cup usage.

Comment: Oh, never mind... I misread your question. You can't use a timer in this way.  "A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. ... If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or while the run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time."

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create timers to fire at specified times.

Use the method `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` of `NSTimer` to create such a timer and add it with `addTimer:forMode:` for `NSRunLoop` to the current run-loop.

My approach would be to create a non-repeating timer to fire at the next full minute and create a new timer every time the previous one fires. This way, you are sure the timer stays in sync with real world time.